# ads.stackoverflow.com delaying the page rendering

Tags: bug, status-norepro, advertising, performance

I would like to report a delay on the rendering of SO.

It seems the culprit is ads.stackoverflow.com

Today ( aug 25 ) I have had some delays. The status bar says.

"Waiting for ads.stackoverflow.com"

I have Firefox 3.5 on OSX 10.5.7

Is not too much, ( just  about 2 seconds ) but I see the rest of the page is there already just waiting for the ads to be fetched.

Comment: Anyone else experiencing this? I didn't notice any issues...

Comment: I do experience at time, however it seems to be a slowdown behind a proxy for me on both cases.

Comment: I'm behind a proxy. I forgot to mention that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be intermittent? Update here if it happens again and is repeatable.

Comment: Again on SF: The bottom of the page is not displayed: http://img197.yfrog.com/i/imagen16ukk.png/

Comment: can't reproduce.

Comment: It's ok, I guess. This is what I do: I use the bottom of the page to jump from one site to another very quickly. So I click and immediately, press page down, to jump to the next ( don't ask me why I just do it like that ). The page content loads instantaneously 99.9% of the times, the  list of questions, links, header everything. But about 8% of the times the foter does not load ( as in the picture )  even though  the question list and everything else is in place. Well I just feel I have to report it. Don't really bothers me. Thanks!!!

Comment: well, we plan to move some multi-site stuff to the header..

Comment: Once again. This time also google analytics got in the middle, I have a video this time :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27931/google-analytics-delaying-the-editing-box-on-stackoveflow

Comment: I have the same problem often, see my answer (just commenting here to make Jeff notice).

Comment: @Jeff `ads.stackoverflow.com` has been down again in the past few days from time to time here in Germany. Direct DSL, no proxy.  Never longer than 10 minutes but noticeable because it makes commenting and editing impossible.

Comment: @pekka I believe that's nightly database backups taking effect and making the BanManPro software (which sucks nearly as bad as Lotus Notes) slow.

Comment: @Jeff I see. Any chance of making the ads asynchronous somehow so the comments functionality (and the highlight fade-out when you post an answer) can load up? It's not really a *big* deal but it's a frequent annoyance.

Comment: @Jeff sorry, but I'm getting rid of ads.stackoverflow.com on my machine now. I'm tired of wanting to comment to something but not being able to because ads is timing out again.

Comment: @pekka your call, but API was also down. This wasn't ads really.

Comment: @Jeff it just really, really sucks that the page is completely unusable when that happens. Especially in Chrome, where the timeout is something like 60 seconds - that's the time you have to wait until you can start writing. Is there nothing that can be done about it? Like `<script async>` or something?

Comment: @Jeff Atwood - It's happening to me now. I have to press Esc to stop the page from loading the ads before I can interact with anything in the page.

Comment: @emt that's because they're upgrading the ad server from 9.0 to 10.0

Comment: @Jeff Atwood - where can I read about tagging using the @ symbol? I was surprised that just "@emt" tagged me.

Comment: @emt see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/new-improved-comments-with-reply/

Answer (score 2):

I am experiencing this too, quite frequently (for a few hours a few days a week). The culprit is `ads.stackoverflow.com` in 90% of the cases and `gravatar.com` in 10%. It's especially annoying because before ads has not loaded, you can't start an answer or write a comment. I'm located in Germany, on a 100 Mbit DSL line in the office, and on a smaller DSL line at home, both with completely different providers. I have had this problem on both lines. In both cases, I'm behind a standard router, but that's it - no Proxies or anything.

I guess some downtime, lag or routing problems can't be helped, but it would be a great help if the page could be designed in a way that you can at least already start typing even if not everything has loaded yet.

Comment: I've seen this as recently as a few hours ago on the other side of the globe, both at work and at home.

Comment: there were unrelated networking problems this morning, so this isn't actually relevant.

Comment: It happens from time to time. It isn't really a big deal, but as I said, if the page could be changed to you can start answering or commenting early, it would be great.

Comment: ... and again, ads down, and no commenting activity possible on SO for about an hour. Not important in the great scheme of things, but still a PITA.