# Delays loading content from ads.stackoverflow.com

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, advertising

Hi,

Your site is great, apart from ads.stackoverflow.com which regularly takes 10+ seconds to respond and greatly disturbs my user experience.  Please could you consider making these servers a touch faster so that I'm not penalised for helping you make some cash!

Thanks.

P.s. - I'm using Chromium / Ubuntu on a UK broadband connection, although I suspect you know that already ;-)

Comment: [This is related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17557/ads-stackoverflow-com-delaying-the-page-rendering)

Comment: @Peter - of course, that was over a year ago... a *long* time in SO

Comment: Though I do not see a ten second delay. I agree that the way we are re-flowing the document and heavily delaying our onload handlers is really problematic